# Do 62% of gay men diagnosed with AIDS practice unsafe sex?

Tags: hiv-aids

[LifeSiteNews Daily News](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/nearly-two-thirds-of-gay-men-who-know-they-have-aids-have-sex-without-condo) reported in 2013 that

> #### Nearly two-thirds of gay men who know they have AIDS have sex without condoms: CDC report
>
> A new report from the Centers for Disease Control (CDC) shows approximately 62 percent of gay men who know they have HIV/AIDS continue to engage in sexual relations without using a prophylactic, a behavior that can spread AIDS.

Is this right?

Answer (score 5):

Such a value is, indeed, a finding of the [CDC report in question.](http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/mm6247a4.htm?s_cid=mm6247a4_w#tab1) The LifeSiteNews article which paraphrases it is (purposefully, I believe) misleading, and fails to invoke the precise quantities listed in the report's additional, specific inquiry pertaining to individuals who were having unprotected sex with *non-positive partners.* As of 2011, only 13% of HIV-positive Men-Who-Have-Sex-With-Men (MSM)¹ undertook such behavior.

The disparity is accountable to men whose partners are *also* HIV-positive. Now, even between two HIV+ individuals, there's upshot in using prophylactics; there *are* other STDs, of course, and even other strains of HIV. But, knowing that ~87% of HIV+ MSM are sticking to partners who also carry the condition, we can reasonably suspect that that many of them act with a sense of conscientiousness, even if they're not making the choice to use condoms, specifically. This conjecture starkly contrasts the LifeSiteNews article's tacit suggestion that a majority of HIV+ gay men are negligently barebacking whoever they please, consequences to their partners' health be damned.

¹ *Interesting lexical aside: In the field of epidemiology, terms such as "gay" and "homosexual" are considered less preferable, because a lot of men-who-have-sex-with-men actually identify as straight. Go figure.*

Comment: I am not knowledgeable in the field of epidemiology, but there is a *very* wide field between "a man having sex with another man" (which would include one-time occurrences, homo-curiosity, non-consensual encounters, or the one special person where one's usual preferences go out of the window) and "a man that is gay / homosexual" (i.e., *identifying* with *preferring* men).

Comment: Where does "in the '80s" come from?

Comment: Shit, I tapped the "post" button too soon- In the 80s, when GRID suddenly made orientation a subject of such immense epidemiological concern,  there was much less validation for sexual gradience and much more stigma for being of non-straight orientation. So there were concomitantly more people who would have elided identifiers like 'bisexual with a preference for women,' or "a two on the Kinsey scale," etc, and the interest was in making sure such people weren't discounted from the studies out of hand.